# Left click button on touchpad not working after update. Any help?

Tags: touchpad

My left click button on touchpad is not working at all, it happened presumably after an update. First I assumed it was an hardware problem but it's not, as it worked flawlessly when i inserted the live DVD to verify. The other features are working as expected.
any solutions ?

Answer (score -1):

I switched to the kernel to 3.16.3. The trouble is gone.